# maxDequeueCount config setting not working for Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

I have an an Azure Function which I want to fail and sent to the poison queue if it errors once or twice. I've set the maxDequeueCount property in my host.json file to 1, but it still retries 5 times. Based on all the doco I've read this seems to be correct. Does anyone have any suggestions? Below is a sample of my hosts.json.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      // For all functions
      "Function": "Trace",
      // Default settings, e.g. for host
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "extensions": {
      "queues": {
        "visibilityTimeout": "00:01:00",
        "maxDequeueCount": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you debugging locally or Azure function is deployed?

Comment: Hi @PranavSingh my function is deployed to Azure

Comment: Were you using storage queue trigger or service bus queue trigger?

Comment: Hi @TonyJu it's a storage queue trigger

Comment: Hi @TonyJu would you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For storage queue trigger, to change frequency of the retry, we just need to change the value of `maxDequeueCount`. Please go to azure portal to check the `host.json` file.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 1
    }
  }
}
```

If the feature still doesn't work after **restarting** the function, I afraid that you need to [raise a support ticket on azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), they will check the backend logs for you.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but your problem was that your "extensions" property was inside your "logging" object rather than at the top level.